# Sharepoint 2007 not displaying certain entities

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

This has been haunting me for days now. I have a simple Multiple lines of text column with the content type as text. I created an XSLT datable and when the data is displayed it would add this `&lt; &gt; &amp; quot; &#39;` and its across all of my data and just can't figure out what I am missing.

Would anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where i am getting your question correctly or not.
Try **disable-output-escaping** in xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="expression" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Optional. "yes" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as is. "no" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as "<". Default is "no"

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix it. If lets say there is a & character in the data it will display &amp;

Comment: try to escape the '&'